# custom dojo stackController icons vs. theme buttons

Tags: javascript, dojo

I tried using the iconClass: on the the contentpane but as expected it but the image on the background. Is there a way to break up the stackcontroller buttons to assign a custom button/img to each of them?

```
<div class="left">
   <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/StackController" data-dojo-props="containerId:'contentStack'">
   </div>
</div>


<div class="centerPanel" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/StackContainer" 
    data-dojo-props="region: 'center',id: 'contentStack'">
        <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" id='iconImg' title="Home" data dojo-props="iconClass: 'iconHpcc'">
            <h4>Dahsboard</h4>
        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you forgot a MINUS in "data dojo-props" within your ContentPane definition. It should be "**data-dojo-props**". Add it and the icon shows up !

Lucian